Why does the last element in a range need to fulfill the heap property for pop_heap?
The C++ standard explains how std::pop_heap is supposed to work:

Effects: Swaps the value in the location first with the value in the location last - 1 and makes
[first, last - 1) into a heap with respect to comp and proj.
C++ Draft

According to this definition, the last element in the given range is placed at the top and then sifted down. Consequently it does not matter whether it fulfilled the heap property before. But the standard insists it has to be part of the heap:

Preconditions: The range [first, last) is a valid non-empty heap with respect to comp and proj.

Even though [first, last - 1) would be sufficient. I do not have access to the actual standard but I assume it does not differ from the draft in this regard, cppreference seems to agree.
This matters when using pop followed by push (for example when using a fixed-size heap to find the smallest n elements in some data, python even has a specific function for this combination of operations) because you need to do the following:
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> my_heap{19, 56, 21, 67, 34};
std::make_heap(my_heap.begin(), my_heap.end());

std::pop_heap(my_heap.begin(), my_heap.end());
my_heap.pop();
my_heap.push_back(new_element);
std::push_heap(my_heap.begin(), my_heap.end());

This takes two heap operations. With the weaker requirement the following would be legal and achieve the same:
my_heap.push_back(new_element);
std::pop_heap(my_heap.begin(), my_heap.end());
my_heap.pop();

This is faster since it does not use push_heap. Note that this already works (at least in gcc), it just does not conform to the standard. So the question is: Why does this requirement exist in this strong form in the standard even though it makes a very common sequence of operations less efficient?

Wouldn’t it be more useful to have a function that just does the sift-down so that you can just swap with my_heap.front() and then run it?  That wouldn’t require temporarily increasing the container size.
